# Does Nginx show X-Accel headers in response?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I try disabling Fast CGI buffering by setting `X-Accel-Buffering: no` header but don't see this header in Nginx response. Is it by design or there's something wrong with my Nginx config? I don't have `fastcgi_ignore_headers` directive.

Comment: By default, nginx does not pass the header fields “Status” and “X-Accel-...” from the response of a FastCGI server to a client. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_hide_header)

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you! I guess it worth to be posted as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, nginx does not pass the header fields “Status” and “X-Accel-...” from the response of a FastCGI server to a client.

To pass it, you will have to add fastcgi_pass_header (X-Accel-Buffering) in nginx config file. Like

```
location ~ \.php$ {
....
fastcgi_pass_header "X-Accel-Buffering";
....
}
```